# In Magento 2 how to change GraphQL sorting and filtering to use the highest price of product variants instead of the lowest?

Tags: php, magento, graphql, magento2

I'm working with GraphQL in my application, specifically with product filtering and sorting. Currently, the system is configured to use the lowest price of the product variants for filtering and sorting purposes. However, I need to modify this behavior to utilize the highest price of the product variants instead.

Additionally, I would like the highest price to be reflected in the aggregations as well. Currently, the aggregations show the lowest price, but I need them to display the highest price of the product variants.

Could someone please guide me on how to make these changes in my GraphQL configuration? I would greatly appreciate any insights, examples, or suggestions on how to achieve this.